# Downgrading Windows 7 Enterprise x64 to Windows 7 Professional x64 or Ultimate x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, 64-bit, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade Windows 7 Enterprise x64 to a Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate x64 installation? Can this be done without doing a clean install?

I am aware that a different license is required for the other versions, but I can not figure out how to actually do the downgrade process.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce features, as unneeded features can be uninstalled or disabled.  Microsoft License 'Downgrade rights' refers to a prior version of the OS.  i.e. downgrading Windows 8 Pro to Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Perhaps this is a case of trying to make a computer with an improper (or reassigned) license a proper one.

Comment: Technically, neither of those is a downgrade from Enterprise. Since Enterprise is VLK licensed, and the others are Retail/OEM sku's there shouldn't be any overlap.

Comment: I've done this a few times before. You just go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System, scroll to the bottom, press "Change product key", and enter the new Pro or Ultimate product key. It's pretty simple, so I'm not sure whether I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Use this tool: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36726-UpDown8-Windows-7-8-Upgrade-Downgrade-Helper to change the edition to Win7 Pro, next run Inplace upgrade with a Win7 Pro DVD/ISO: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html